# An experiment with light

Tags: quantum-optics

Consider a hollow sphere which have an inside, made of purely reflecting material . Now if we can introduce some amount of light, inside of the sphere, what will happen next?

Comment: This is a variant of a thought-experiment in Gamow, Thirty Years That Shook Physics, p.13 ff.

Comment: resonance will happen=) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_cavity

Comment: What will be, if we introduce light rays in two different phases?  Would not the photons collide with each other, any time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, normal mirror is not completely reflective, so in a "spherical mirror", the light would quickly dissipate.
However, you specified a purely reflective material, one that is 100% reflective. We should also specify that the inside is a perfect vacuum, since the light would otherwise eventually be absorbed by the air. (Note that perfect vacuums don't really exist. Even in the space between galaxies isn't entirely empty) In that case, the light would, I suspect, bounce around forever. Of course, it could not be observed, as to look at it would require light to enter into your eyes, or the camera, etc, and would diminish the light in the sphere, not to mention the light that would be absorbed by the body of whatever object is doing the looking.

Comment: And the question of how to get light inside in the first place remains...

Comment: Yes, it does. But as this is a hypothetical situation in the first place, I decided to ignore it. I did think about it though, but all I came up with is maybe some kind of element that decays over time, releasing light as it does.